# Jacobian matrix problem of a function of $ \Bbb R ^ 3 \to \Bbb R ^ 2 $.

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I think the exercise has an error, and it should be $ F (x, y, z) $.

Now, let's find $ J_F $.

$$J_F(x,y,z)=\begin{bmatrix}
2x\cos(x^2+3z) &0  &3\cos(x^2+3z) \\ 
-2y\sin(2xy) &-2x\sin(2xy)  & 4z
\end{bmatrix}$$

What I don't understand are the other questions, in the one that follows they give me three variables, but in the others they give me only 2. Someone could help me with that, I don't even know what they ask me to do. To guide me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Sorry. I put it, because I wanted to state the exercise correctly and then rate the error. @DietrichBurde